# Why does my LSM303 magnetometer reading not change in a while loop?

Tags: arduino

I am using a LSM303 sensor to compute a heading and I want to turn my robot to a heading.

I have the simple code here:

```
int mag;
mag = compass.heading((LSM303::vector){0,-1,0});;   //read the angle of the robot

Serial.println(mag);
while (mag != angle){   
    //while it isn't the desired angle turn and continue to update the robot angle      
    trex.write(0xE9);
    trex.write(90);
    trex.write(90);
    mag = compass.heading((LSM303::vector){0,-1,0});;   //read the angle of the robot


}
```

In a function called with a speed and angle (heading), the trex part tells the motor controller to turn on a point and the while loop should test for when the desired heading is reached. However, testing using a couple of instances of `Serial.println(mag);` I have determined that once inside the while loop, mag never changes which just means the robot turns indefinitely.

I have no idea why this would happen. Perhaps someone here does?

Thanks.

Comment: if mag is not changing, then compass.heading(...) should be investigated to see if your i2c implementation is correct. Did you test the compass for working condition at any time?

Comment: Yes - sorry probably should have mentioned, if I run `mag = compass.heading((LSM303::vector){0,-1,0});;` by itself and then move the compass and run it again it performs correctly and the heading changes as expected.

Comment: I am confused here, if mag changes when robot turns, it should change inside the while loop since the robot is rotating constantly? question: is angle the desired angle and mag the actual angle? Have you had a print inside the while loop?

Comment: Another thought... Do you need some time delay between readings? I am not familiar with your compass, but the documentation should indicate any constraints that you need to pay attention to.

Comment: "I am confused here, if mag changes when robot turns, it should change inside the while loop since the robot is rotating constantly?" That's what I thought, I doubted myself and thought perhaps I really didn't understand the fundamentals of while loops as much as I thought.

Comment: Angle is the desired angle and mag is the actual angle yes. And I must look into if it perhaps needs a delay that may be the problem. thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, can I mark this as solved? or close it? There is no answer for me to mark as correct

Comment: Post your solution, it may help other people.

Comment: You could always debug this in 2 parts: First, write the compass.heading value directly to the serial port and verify that it changes.  Second, set the value of mag based on a timer: desired heading for 1 second, 90 degrees offset for the following second, then repeat.  The first test will validate the compass, the second test will validate that the compiler is handling variables in the way that you expect.

Comment: You CAN (and are actually encouraged) to post your own answer.  You can also accept it.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Arduino from Aardvark, so this comment is based purely on how a modern C++ compiler would behave:

Were you asking about a plain ol' C++ problem, I would ask you if compass is declared volatile, or if the 'heading' method of compass's class is declared volatile, or if your system is based on cooperative multitasking.

In the first two cases (lack of things being tagged as volatile) the compiler will optimize the call to compass.heading to just outside the loop (to save you time -- isn't that nice?).

In the third case, whatever the code is that actually acquires the values for the compass structure will never get a chance to run (because your code is stuck in the while loop) and you'll never see results.

I hope this makes sense to the Arduino environment...